# What is the purpose and how to use CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION in Camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

When setting manual controls in Android by using the Camera2 API, what is the purpose of [CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION)?

I have read several times the **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION)** but still can’t understand its purpose, and what value to set in relation to the exposure time and ISO.

I understand the CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME specifies how much light is the sensor letting in; also that the CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY is the sensor sensitivity to light (ISO), but no idea about SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION and how it relates to the exposure time and sensor sensitivity.

For example, if I set a long exposure time of 1 second or 30 seconds, then what is the value that I should set in SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION? And how does it relate to the other sensor controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FRAME_DURATION is the same concept as output frame rate.  That is, how often is an image read out from the image sensor?  Frame rate is generally reported as frames per second, while FRAME_DURATION is the inverse of that - the duration of a single frame.

Since the camera2 API is all about per-frame control, having the duration as a per-frame property is appropriate.

FRAME_DURATION can't be shorter than EXPOSURE_TIME (since you can't read the image from the sensor until exposure is complete), but the API handles this for you - if you ask for a FRAME_DURATION that's too short compared to EXPOSURE_TIME, it gets automatically increased.

That said, often you may want consistent frame rate (such as 30fps for video recording), so you'd set your FRAME_DURATION to 1/30s = 33333333 ns, and then vary EXPOSURE_TIME for manual exposure control.  As long as you keep EXPOSURE_TIME as less than 1/30s, you'll get steady frame rate and still have manual exposure control.

The minimum possible frame duration (and therefore the maximum frame rate) depends on the output resolution(s) and format(s) you've asked for in the camera capture session.  Generally, bigger resolutions take longer to read out, putting a limit on minimum frame duration.   Cameras that support the BURST_CAPTURE camera capability can handle at least 20fps for 8 MP captures, or better.

At the image sensor level, frame duration is implemented by adding in extra vertical blanking time so that EXPOSURE + VBLANK = FRAME_DURATION.  The full picture is also more complicated in that typical CMOS image sensors can be exposing some rows of the image while others are being read out (rolling shutter) so the actual timing diagrams look more complicated.  You don't generally have to care when just doing basic manual exposure control, however.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the image sensors in a smart phone are using rolling shutter, which readout pixels line by line, the `FRAME_DURATION = FRAME_READ_OUT_TIME + VBLANK`.